# Is there an app or site for discovering live music in my area but more for bands that are not so big and famous?

Tags: live-music

Is there an app or site for discovering live music in my area but more for bands that are not so big and famous? Something like https://www.bandsintown.com but for bands that basically just use facebook events for promotion on the interwebs, and hang posters at the gig site?

Comment: Why can't you use a browser and go to a web site featuring local events?

Comment: That's kinda my point. So for the use case of "wants to know what live music is playing near them" the solution is "google around and hope that the group or someone at the site (a bar manager? pshh yah right..) made a facebook event (or whatever they use to publish events, if they even do - and btw - most of them don't...).

Comment: wow. what snobby trolls are downvoting a fairly reasonable question lol. At least tell me why - off topic, maybe not appropriate for this site? Educate me maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, facebook's Events became basically the only reason i use facebook, so "for bands that basically just use facebook events for promotion" facebook should be the way to go.

"Like" the most important locations in your area and you should be good to go.
Activate e-mail notifications and you don't even have to visit facebook to be up-to-date.

I don't think that aggregating facebook-events outside of facebook makes much sence - which value could be added? facebook does already a great job here...

Comment: thanks! I agree, facebook seems to be the winner, for better or worse. re: `I don't think that aggregating facebook-events outside of facebook makes much sence ` I actually saw an app using faceboook api to retrieve events I believe it was `bandsintown` app - but it's not working right now :(